# jQuery Ajax MVC 4 app

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am following a blog [Ajax and jQuery in ASP.NET MVC](http://chsakell.com/2013/05/10/ajax-and-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc/)

My Model Class:

```
namespace Chekout.Models
{
    [Table(Name = "Products")]
    public class Product
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
namespace Chekout.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {  
        //dbContextDataContext is my dbml class which was not generated in the blog.   
        dbContextDataContext dbContext = null;

        public ProductController()
        {
            this.dbContext = new dbContextDataContext(Connection.connectionString);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Product/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //Products[] product = dbContext.GetTable().ToArray(); 

              //The Above Statement gives me Error! Why? Am i not following the blog?

            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

I want to select, update, insert, delete data via jquery ajax in MVC application. I was following the above blog but that is not helping me. Please specify what am I doing wrong or am I not following the blog.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: and what is your view like?
did you miss something simple like include jquery as reference?

Comment: i am getting this error
The type arguments for method 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext.GetTable<TEntity>()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Well, I have got this error in Controller, I have not yet created a view and this is giving me the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the compiler cannot infer type of objects that you want to fetch you have to specify it. For example:

```
Products[] product = dbContext.GetTable<Products>().ToArray();
```

More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.gettable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).